# My Application Exits on parsing an int value

Tags: c#, parsing, exception

My Application Exits when i parse a string to int.. I can't solve the problem as I am new to C# in-fact I am new to Programming,  Here is my code so far:

```
public string Reverse(string str)
{
  int num = int.Parse(str);
  int reverse = 0;
  while(num > 0)
  {
    reverse *= 10;
    reverse += num % 10;
    num /= 10;
  }
  return (reverse.ToString());
}
```

I don't want it to quit the Application

Comment: is the value valid int?

Comment: Is this a command line exe?  winforms?  wpf?  You need to give more information.  What is calling your method?

Comment: it is a console app @roryap

Comment: it is ok when i input  a correct string but exits when an invalid string is passed @EhsanSajjad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `TryParse` pattern instead:

```
int parsedNumber;
var success = int.TryParse("1", out parsedNumber);
```

On another note, a much better `Reverse` algorithm is to do:

```
public static string Reverse(string s)
{
    char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(charArray);
    return new string(charArray);
}
```